# Could not find stored procedure "sys.sp_cdc_enable_db_internal"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to CDC so I started investigating the stored procedures that enable CDC in an SQL Server database. Examining `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` and I get the message Could not find stored procedure `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db_internal`. I've looked all over my database and in the master and msdb databases. Please could anyone tell me why SSMS can't find this stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is available only in SQL Server Enterprise and Developer editions, starting with. It can be enabled only using system stored procedures. SQL Server Management Studio provides a wide range of code templates for various feature related actions

**To open the templates:**

1. In the SQL Server Management Studio menu, open View
2. Click Template
3. Open SQL Server Templates
4. Open the Change Data Capture sub-folder. The T-SQL templates for administration, configuration, enumeration and meta data querying are available
   [image]

**To set up the feature:**

Make sure SQL Server Agent is running. If not, right-click it in Object Explorer and click Start

To enable the feature on the database, open the Enable Database for CDC template in the Configuration sub-folder, and replace the database name with the name of the database you want to track

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
    GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
    GO
```

The login used must have SQL Server sysadmin privileges and must be a db_owner of the database. Otherwise, you’ll get the following error

> sg 22830, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_enable_db_internal, Line
> 193 The failure occurred when executing the command
> ‘SetCDCTracked(Value = 1)’. The error returned was 15517: ‘Cannot
> execute as the database principal because the principal “dbo” does not
> exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not
> have permission.’. Use the action and error to determine the cause of
> the failure and resubmit the request.

Vist For More Information

https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/enable-use-sql-server-change-data-capture/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your detailed answer. I have already enabled CDC for my database, enabled CDC for a table using sys.sp_cdc_enable_table, understand about captured column lists and know where the CDC data goes. My question was, when looking at the definition of sys.sp_cdc_enable_db, SSMS is telling me it can't find the stored procedure sys.sp_cdc_enable_db_internal. Does anyone know why please? Thanks